# Retrofit use only setEndpoint() and in the @PUT leave empty in android

Tags: android, retrofit

i am trying to use the RestAdapter with setEndpoint(BASE_URL), and in the interface leave the @PUT(null), is it possible?
the reason why is because i am getting the URL as an answer from the server and i just need this URL  to call PUT.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean you get the URL as an answer from the server? When do you get the URL? When you do a PUT to your BASE_URL?

Comment: Some code would be helpful to highlight what you have done and what you want to complete.

Comment: My problem is that i am getting in different GET a return a object with URL inside, and i want to do a PUT with this new URL and i need or the Endpoint to be null and the PUT to be null ' so i can fill it with the full path URL that i got. @raxelsson

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, but if I were you I would try to write it like the endpoint you want to call, is dynamically added with the retrofit URL manipulation "@Path("")".

```
@PUT("{endPoint}")
void somethingSomething(@Path("endpoint") String endPoint, Callback<T> cb)
```

And then have the base url set in the retrofit restadapter when you initialize it.